# How do I move an object from off screen to just off screen? (Unity2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an enemy that can constantly move quite far away when the player moves too much, so I want to move it to the just off screen so it can move back into view without appearing suddenly. It would also be nice to have them reappear in the same direction from where they left. Currently have this just to check if .isVisible was working;

```
if(GetComponent<Renderer>().isVisible == false)
{
    Debug.Log("Off Screen");
    this.transform.Translate(0, distanceFromPlayer - 5, 0);
}
```

Having a constant distance wouldn't work because it would either appear on screen as if it was teleporting or appear too far off screen and not make it back. I understand how Camera.WorldToScreenPoint works, just couldn't find a way to make them appear in the same direction.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint.html)

So if you wanted to put them outside the left of the screen, you could do
cam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0 - enemyScreenOffset,.5,cam.nearClipPlane));

or if you wanted the upper right side of the screen
cam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1 + enemyScreenOffset,1,cam.nearClipPlane));

It depends on how your game works, but you might want to change the Z component of the Vector3 to be the enemyPosition so they don't change height.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but that teleports the enemy to a fixed position, meaning it will always teleport them to the bottom right, or top left. I was thinking more like the code example I added, except it swaps the distanceFromPlayer - 5 for a distance from the edge of the screen - 0.5.

Comment: If you want a direct offset from the player, get the players offset in x/z using https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToViewportPoint.html, and then replace that in the enemies position.

Or you could do Random.Range(0,1f) to randomly move them along either axis on the screen for some randomness. 
Alternatively, pair the two. So get the player's X/Z viewport position, and then randomly add an offset like -0.2 to 0.2 to have them be offset but have a slighlty different position each time